# JS file upload validation, but instant in windows window

Tags: javascript, forms, file, upload, window

I have a form and did validation in JS, that the form is not send when user sends sth different than .doc/.docx. (CV uploading).
But I want this faster. To get the error instantly when the file is selected, not when the button is submitted. (in windows window).

How to do it? It's standard form:

```
<div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Your CV</label>
                                        <input required type="file" accept="application/msword" class="form-control" name="cv" id="cv" aria-describedby="name" placeholder="Select a CV file"/>
                                    </div>
```

Comment: Can't replicate on Windows 10. When browsing files it automatically applies `Word 2003 Document` filter (hiding the files that don't validate to that).

Answer (score 0):

I've just got an answer. Here's the code (isDoc is my own function):

```
    function onChange(event) {
         var file = $('#file_cv')[0].files[0];
         if ( !isDoc(file.name) ) {
            alert("Please, choose .doc or .docx type.");
            document.getElementById("file_cv").value="";
}
}
```

Now, it's impossible to submit form without sending proper file.